# VBA subroutine returns error on second run

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Sooo, i had a nice little subroutine that would remove all but a single row in a table.

```
Sub ClearFormTableRows(sourceRange, countRange)
Dim rowsCount As Integer, rowRangeName As Object
rowsCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(countRange)
With sourceRange

    Do Until rowsCount = 1

        .ListObject.ListRows(2).Delete
        rowsCount = rowsCount - 1
        If rowsCount = 1 Then Exit Do
    Loop

End With
End Sub
```

And until today it worked. But in the main routine that calls it i added another call, same syntax just for a different table and now it wont do anything, throws an error 9 subroutine out of range.
The row it highlights is this one: `.ListObject.ListRows(2).Delete`
But, if i comment out either of the calls, it doesn't matter which, it will execute properly on that table. But ask it to do both and it wont do either.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Post all of the relevant code.

Comment: Do you mean "subscript out of range"?  Most likely excel is complaining that your list object doesn't have a second row, so there is a problem with how you're assigning your `rowsCount` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way: I removed `rowRangeName object` as it's not in use for given snippet in your question.

```
  Sub ClearFormTableRows(ByRef sourceRange as Range, ByRef countRange As Range)
     Dim rowsCount As Integer
     Dim objListObj As ListObject 
     Dim objListRows As ListRows 

     Set objListObj = sourceRange.ListObjects(1) 
     Set objListRows = objListObj.ListRows 
     rowsCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(countRange)

     While rowsCount > 1
     '-- just a re-confirmation, you can remove first if condition if you want.
     If (rowsCount > 1) And (rowsCount < objListRows.Count - 1) Then 
        objListRows(rowsCount).Delete 
        rowsCount = rowsCount - 1
     End If 
     Wend
  End Sub
```

Reference:

- [ListObject.ListRows Property (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834452.aspx)

PS: Might not be related, but please declare parameters explicitly with either `ByRef` or `ByVal` :

`Sub ClearFormTableRows(ByRef sourceRange As Range, ByRef countRange As Range)` :)

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for your help. Special thanks for the links so i can understand whats going on.

Comment: Glad you got it worked `:D`